# How to Find and reload specific driver from kernel?

Tags: debian, kernel, wifi, drivers, crunchbang

I am using Crunchbang 64 bit O.S. with a ASUS N150 wireless adapter. Every time I close my laptop and it enters sleep mode, when I "wake it up" I am unable to connect back using the wireless adapter; I have to restart.

My questions are:

1. Is there a way to find the specific driver name? I know it's an ASUS N150 adapter with a Realtek chipset.
2. How can I reload the driver for the adapter without resetting the system?
3. How can I find my current kernel version via terminal (sidenote)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## way to find the specific driver name

- `lspci | grep -i network`

I am not sure whether that device is on the PCI or USB bus but you can try the following.

1. Use `lsusb` or `lspci` to find information about the device
2. Lookup that device for the corresponding module ("driver")
3. Make sure that module is loaded and available with `lsmod` and `modprobe`

Another Idea would be to use `lsmod` and `diff` to find out which modules are going missing when your laptop uses sleep mode. It could be more than one module that has a problem.

1. restart machine
2. make sure that the wifi adapter is working
3. use `lsmod` to get all loaded modules

   ```
   lsmod > loaded-modules-before-sleep.txt
   ```
4. put computer to sleep mode
5. wake machine up
6. make sure that the wifi adapter ISN'T working
7. use `lsmod` to get all loaded modules

   ```
   lsmod > loaded-modules-after-sleep.txt
   ```
8. use diff to see what has changed!

   ```
   diff loaded-modules-before-sleep.txt loaded-modules-after-sleep.txt
   ```

## reload driver without resetting system

Once you know the module to load, simply use `modprobe` as root

- `modprobe wifi_module_name`

## find current kernel version via terminal

`uname` to the rescue! `uname` should tell you what you want to know.

- `uname -a`

Comment: Worked! But I now a new question arises. What is 'cfg80211' and it's purpose?

Comment: [A quick search for this module](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/Documentation/cfg80211) seems to show it is related to WiFi communication between user <-> kernel space. I would suggest reloading this module and seeing if WiFi works or not. you can also run `dmesg` to get some debugging info about any errors that may arise.

Comment: Alternatively, you could use `readlink` and resolve the target of **/sys/class/net/<intf>/device/driver**.  For example, on my system (I still use the *ethN* moniker) `readlink /sys/class/net/eth0/device/driver` resolves to `../../../bus/pci/drivers/e1000e`.  Thus, the driver is *e1000e.ko*.  You would load via `modprobe e1000e`.  You would need to know the interface name for your WiFi device.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a shorter and more specific answer for my own convenience :)

To find out the kernel module, issue `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` (from [ubuntu WifiDocs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx)):

```
~$ lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network 
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Apple Inc. AirPort Extreme [106b:010f]
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 256 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 17
    Region 0: Memory at a0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: wl
    Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

From this you can see that `wl` is in use.

To reload on demand, do

```
sudo rmmod wl && sudo modprobe wl
```

To reload on sleep/hibernate, install pm-utils and add a file with any name in `/etc/pm/config.d/`, for instance `/etc/pm/config.d/suspend` with the following contents:

```
SUSPEND_MODULES="wl"
```

This is explained at [Arch pm-utils wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pm-utils) and [pm-action man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/pm-action)