# Manual vs automatic suspend: If there are differences, how can I investigate them?

Tags: debian, gnome, power-management, suspend

Are there any differences in the way [suspend](https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend) functions automatically (such as clicking lock and the computer suspending after a while) compared to manually (such as actively clicking the suspend button)?

With "functions" I try to convey processes that are activated/deactivated, or, the effects of the initial change--either automatic or manual--to the system. How do they affect the system, kernel, desktop, [et cetera](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Power_management/Suspend_and_hibernate)?

If the processes differ, can someone please refer me to how I can examine this?

I suspect a difference may be a reason [monitors](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/746739/why-after-suspend-only-sometimes-not-detect-usb-or-deactivates-driver-and-how) sometimes don't come back. Another reason may be [firmware](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747205/is-it-possible-to-reactivate-not-reload-a-driver-from-running-kernel?noredirect=1#comment1421819_747205) that I cannot hope to fix.

My setup is Debian bullseye with Gnome desktop and tlp/tlp ui installed.